# Absolute Convergence of a Series (maybe use ratio test)

Tags: real-analysis, ratio, absolute-convergence

Let

$p:=\lim_{{k \to \infty}} k(1-|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|)$

Prove

$p>1$ or  $p=\infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converge absolutely

Comment: $p=\infty\implies p>1$, you really only need to prove the $p>1$ case. That said, start by considering when $\lim_{k\to\infty}k\left(1-\left\lvert\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right\rvert\right)<1$. What must be true of $a_k$ for this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma 1: If $s\notin\mathbb{Z}_{\le 0}$, then $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+ax)(1-x)^a-1}{x^2} $$ exists and is non-zero.

proof: $(1+ax)(1-x)^a=\left(1+ax\right)\left( 1-ax+\frac{a(a-1)}{2}x^2+o(x^2)\right) =1-\frac{a^2+a}{2}x^2+o(x^2)$ which is the rephrasement of our lemma.

Lemma 2: If $s\notin\mathbb{Z}_{\le 0}$, then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(s+1)\cdots(s+n)}{n^s\cdot n!} $$ exists and is not zero.

proof: Let $$b_n=\frac{s(s+1)\cdots(s+n)}{n^s\cdot n!}.$$ Then\begin{align*}
 \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=&\left( 1+\frac{s}{n+1}\right) \left( 1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^s\\=&1+\frac{c}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right)  \text{  for some constant $c$ .}
\end{align*}
(The last step uses lemma 1 and sequence being $o\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$ are also $o\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right) $.)

Then $b_n=b_1\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{b_i}{b_{i-1}}=e^{\sum_{i=2}^n \ln\frac{b_{n_+1}}{b_n}}$. Since $\ln\frac{b_{n_+1}}{b_n}\sim \left( \frac{b_{n_+1}}{b_n}-1\right)\sim  \frac{c}{n^2}$ we conclude $\sum_{i=2}^n \ln\frac{b_{n_+1}}{b_n}$ converges, which implies $b_n$ converges to a non-zero real number.

Finally we return to the question. The hypothesis implies that there exists $d>1$ s.t. for sufficiently large $k$, $\bigg|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \bigg|<1-\frac{d}{k}$ $\implies$ $$a_k<M\prod_{l=N}^k \left( 1-\frac{d}{k}\right)=M\prod_{l=N}^k\left(\frac{k-d}{k} \right)  $$ for some $M$, $N$. Lemma 2 says $a_n\sim Mc\frac{n^{-d}n!}{n!}\sim A\cdot n^{-d}$ for some $A$. Since $d<1$ we conclude $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|<+\infty$.

Comment: Doesn’t $a_n$ converge to a non-zero real numbers implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverge?

Comment: @JohnFrank The sequence in the lemma is also denoted by $a_n$. I confess this is not good writing style because it abuses notation. I will edit that.

Comment: I am really new to real analysis. Can I ask what exactly does $\sim$ mean?

Comment: @JohnFrank  This is the equivalent symbol. "$a_n\sim b_n$, $n\to \infty$" means $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$. "$f(x)\sim g(x)$, $x\to a$" means $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$. There is also "$f(x)\sim g(x)$, $x\to a+$", "$f(x)\sim g(x)$, $x\to a-$", "$f(x)\sim g(x)$, $x\to +\infty$" and so forth. The limit which $x$ tends to can vary, but it always means $\frac{f}{g}$ converges to $1$ when $x$ tend to the corresponding limit.

Comment: Please elaborate on $\ln \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \sim \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}-1$.

Comment: @JohnFrank We know (1) $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\to 1$, $n\to \infty$ since $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1+\frac{c}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right)  $. (2) $\ln x\sim x-1$ as $x\to 0$ (This is a rephrasement of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=1$, which I assume you are familiar). Heine's theorem allows us to plug in $x=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ in $\ln x\sim x-1$, $x\to 0$ and we get $\ln \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \sim \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}-1$, $n\to\infty$.